# Hiding a RadioButton in Android

Tags: android, android-view

I want to set the visibility of a RadioButton to INVISIBLE or GONE. For some reason this isn't working.

```
RadioButton myRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.my_radio_button_id);
myRadioButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or

```
myRadioButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

No error is returned, it just doesn't do anything.

However I have tried this on the RadioGroup

```
RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup_quiz_answers);
myRadioGroup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

And it works fine to hide the whole group. Is there a way to just hide one of the RadioButtons? I have a group of 3 which are answers to questions but in some cases I want to hide the last one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can hide the particular radio button this way

```
RadioButton myRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.last_radio);
myRadioButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

or if you use View Gone menas radio button hide with sapce

```
RadioButton myRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.last_radio);
myRadioButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In that case do not hide the radio group

```
RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup_quiz_answers);
myRadioGroup.setVisibility(View.Visible);
```

Comment: whats the difference? in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Hi use like this.

```
RadioButton myRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.my_radio_button_id);
myRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myRadioButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

**OR**

```
  <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

This code is working for me.Hope this will help you.

Comment: This does work, however in the format above (where I programmatically hide it in the onCreate method) it doesn't. Unfortunately making it hide when it's clicked doesn't help me in this situation.

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom see my edited answer you can do it in XML itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final TableLayout bilgiAlani=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.bilgiAlani);
    final RadioButton secim1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.butonSecim1);
    final TextView bilgiMesaji=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bilgiMesaji);
    secim1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (secim1.isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "secildi",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bilgiAlani.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bilgiMesaji.setText("birinci seicmbirinci seicmbirinci seicmbirinci seicmbirinci\n seicmbirinci seicm" +
                        "birinci seicmbirinci seicmbirinci seicmbirinci seicm" +
                        "birinci seicmbirinci seicm ");
            }
            else if(!secim1.isChecked()) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Secmekten Vazgecildi",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bilgiAlani.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bilgiMesaji.setText("birinci secilmedi");
            }

        }
    });
```